# Set up a repeating 24:00:00 countdown timer which stops and resets at 00:00:00

Tags: timer, swiftui

Right now im getting a countdown timer which actually has the form "24:00:00". The problem is that the timer keeps running after being at "00:00:00" and starts counting down negative numbers. What i want is the timer to stop at 0 and repeat at 24 hours. My problem is that the time is of the Data.type Date(). so i don't know how to explain with an if statement that the textlabel should change if the countdown timer == 0. I hope you understand the problem

```
struct ContentView: View {

  // Timer

 func countDownString(from referenceDate: Date, until nowDate: Date) -> String
 {
     let components = calender.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: nowDate, to: referenceDate)

     return String(format: "%02dh:%02dm:%02ds",
                   components.hour ?? 00,
                   components.minute ?? 00,
                   components.second ?? 00)


 }


@State var nowDate: Date = Date()
let referenceDate: Date = Date().addingTimeInterval(20)
let calender = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let formatter = DateFormatter()


var timer: Timer {
   Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) {_ in
       self.nowDate = Date()

   }


 }


 var body: some View {

 Text(countDownString(from: referenceDate, until: nowDate)).font(.largeTitle).onAppear(perform: {
                    _ = self.timer

                })
}
}
```

Comment: Would you show your code?

Comment: of course. i will add it to my question